# Log file locking when using EL 4.0 Logging Block

Tags: .net, asp.net, logging, enterprise-library

Using EL 4.0 makes it any better to avoid creating  new file with a GUID prepended to its name? If I dont want to create a new files every time the if the file is locked. What is the best possible approach I can take to avoid this.

Comment: Can you supply more detail?  What is the approach that it is causing log files to be locked?

Comment: Assume its a general lock...When two request trying to access a same log file..one request is actually writing to the log file.

Comment: Here's the response from CodePlex on this issue: http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/268665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enterprise library 5.0 has a feature to support this issue. This also could be resolve by queuing the request  using Message Queue in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Each file based trace listener that you define will lock the output file.  If the file cannot be logged to then the GUID will be prepended to the file name.  This is the behavior you are seeing.

Usually this is caused with multiple trace listeners trying to log to a single file or multiple processes trying to log to a single file.

To avoid this behavior ensure that you are using only one trace listener per output file.  If you are trying to log to one file from multiple processes then you could consider a database trace listener or using a centralized logging service (e.g. [Distributor Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647847.aspx))